# How do we refer to a item in a numbered list

Tags: single-word-requests, lists

I have a longer text. Let's say I have a numbered list, like this,

> (1) Item 1
>
> (2) Item 2
>
> (3) Item 3

Later I want to reference the list, such as

> As described above, cf. [this is where the word should be inserted] (1) and (2), we observe that beef is very unhealthy.

However, numbers in brackets (1) are already reserved for formulas in my text. How can I reference these points? I was thinking about "bullet point (1)" and "bullet point (2)". However, they aren't really bullet points. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you actually need a word?

Comment: Yes, otherwise it could be mistaken for formula (1)

Comment: Given no other context, I would choose *item* or *point*. However, if they have some other common purpose, I would use that. Like, *statement* or *fact*.

Comment: When you introduce your list, that is your opportunity to label the entries as X. "*Here is a list of X*." Then you refer to X 1 or X 2, such as point 1 or point 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a name for the list and refer to the items of the list.
E.g.

```
Reasons:
(1) Item 1
(2) Item 2
(3) Item 3
```

> As described above, cf. Reasons (1) and (2), we observe that beef is very unhealthy.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Roman numeration: (i), (ii), (iii), (iv) etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, Roman numeration is already used as a sub-numbering.

Comment: Well, then it becomes difficult. However, bear in mind that references such as ""bullet point (1)" are likely to tire the reader besides not being economical. In what context do you have to resort to so many types of enumeration?

Comment: The piece is very technical. Therefore, enumerating different groups is very helpful and necessary...